# ASP.NET GridView Deletion 'Input string was not in a correct format'

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, gridview, onclientclick

I have an ASP.NET GridView that displays clothing products from my database. A field in my database is Price and to display this as £xxx.xx I have set the Price DataFormatString to {0:C}.

The GridView also has a delete button which I have converted to a template and added

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product?');"
```

to add a confirmation message once the button is clicked. However, when I click OK to confirm deletion of the product I get this error message:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

When I take the DataFormatString out of the GridView so that the prices are displaying as the default xxx.xxxx, the delete function works fine. It is only when the DataFormatString is present that I get this error. How do I get around this? Help appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div id="GridView">
    <asp:GridView ID="ProductsGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellSpacing="-1" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="ProductsGridView_DS" GridLines="None" CssClass="ProductsGrid"     AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this     product?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Available" HeaderText="Available" SortExpression="Available" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stock" HeaderText="Stock" SortExpression="Stock" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="UploadImage.aspx?Id={0}" Text="Upload Image" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProductsGridView_DS" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db_1318766_zaraConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Products] WHERE     [Id] = @original_Id AND [Name] = @original_Name AND [Description] = @original_Description AND [Gender] = @original_Gender AND [Type] = @original_Type AND [Price] = @original_Price AND (([Available] = @original_Available)     OR ([Available] IS NULL AND @original_Available IS NULL)) AND [Stock] = @original_Stock" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Products] ([Name], [Description], [Gender], [Type], [Price], [Available], [Stock]) VALUES (@Name,     @Description, @Gender, @Type, @Price, @Available, @Stock)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Products]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Products] SET [Name] = @Name, [Description] =     @Description, [Gender] = @Gender, [Type] = @Type, [Price] = @Price, [Available] = @Available, [Stock] = @Stock WHERE [Id] = @original_Id AND [Name] = @original_Name AND [Description] = @original_Description AND [Gender]     = @original_Gender AND [Type] = @original_Type AND [Price] = @original_Price AND (([Available] = @original_Available) OR ([Available] IS NULL AND @original_Available IS NULL)) AND [Stock] = @original_Stock">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Gender" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Type" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Available" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Stock" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Available" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Stock" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Available" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Stock" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Gender" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Type" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Available" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Stock" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could reduce the problem to a contrived page with actual code, so that I can reproduce and work on it? For instance, I assume that part about the confirmation alert has nothing to do with the actual error.

Comment: Hi, there is no C# - it's just a simple ASP.NET webform with HTML and ASP.NET controls. I have added the .aspx page code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simplifying your delete statement?

Example:

```
DELETE FROM [Products] WHERE [Id] = @original_Id
```

I say this because I see you delete statement requires: "AND [Price] = @original_Price". Your price formatting might be affecting you delete statement.

Hence when you remove it (the price formatting). Everything seems to work fine again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Tried it but still get the same error.

Comment: OK I see. Did you reduce you "DeleteParameters" at the same time?

Comment: Ah no I hadn't done that. Just tried it though and it works! Thank you!